# Windows audio installed but not recognized

Tags: usb, audio, windows-8.1, midi

Something shredded my ability to use MIDI and hear sound or properly change settings on the playback.

This is a very strange thing and superuser the last place I seek help before buying a new computer.

I have installed properly the latest drivers for Windows 8.1 for the device Focusrite Scarlett 18i20 2nd gen.

[image]

I can see in and output using the Focusrite control software or simply by looking at the meters,
but windows does not recognize them properly:

[image]

It doesn't even show up deactivated devices or system standard devices or anything.

This is a real problem. What is possibly wrong?`Everything has worked since a few days ago, I don't know what was causing this. Probably RIOT Vanguard which I have uninstalled without bringin sound back up.

Left clicking on the volume in the system tray looks like this:

[image]

I have gone through the Windows Event Log and did not find anything but the message that I have successfully installed the driver (I tried reinstalling them).

The problem began when I installed RIOT's anti cheat software Vanguard, which at some point in time popped up the message "blocked asio.dll".

ASIO is playing a key role in this.

After uninstalling Vanguard, the asio.dll never came back and I suspect that system changes have been made I cannot undo.

My system repair does not cover more than 24 hours it seems and the problems started several days ago. Strangely, I can hear sound, so USB and the hardware ARE working.

Another in example: I cannot select any audio device in Discord.

Comment: This appears to be a software problem. Repairing or reinstalling Windows should help.

Comment: @CL. tried various system-repair commands and tools, no luck

Comment: You have to try a repair or install from a Windows install disk.

Answer (score 0):

The best MIDI playback I've found is using third-party tools, such as free [Faclosoft's MIDI Player](https://falcosoft.hu/softwares.html), or free [MidiSheetMusic](http://midisheetmusic.com/download.html). Installing either of these may also entail installing a sound font, such as [that from Falcosoft](https://falcosoft.hu/reality_gmgs_falcomod.zip).

Vielleicht, installing the sound font could fix the Windows Player, too.

Comment: Tried several MIDI drivers but even successfully installed they dont get through to windows' application layer. thx for your answer tho, worth a try.